# Cutting an inner tie-rod: how

Tags: steering

Attempting to replace inner+outer tie-rods.  Situation: outer tie rod is screwed-in and showing strong resistance to being unscrewed.  The outer tie rod must be removed in order to apply the tie-rod tool to unseat the inner tie-rod.

It was suggested that the inner tie-rod could be severed \ sawed to remove the outer tie rod.  If this was to be done is it possible \ practical to use a hack saw or does a motorized saw need to be used?

I would really like to hear from anyone that has done this before: please state this in your response if you have sawed-off a tie-rod.

Comment: Is this on the Acura? I'm not aware of a special tool you need to separate the inner tie rod? I just did the inner tie rod on a Civic which should be the same. I just used a large Cresent wrench to remove it from the rack and pinion. There is a lock nut on the inner, but that just deforms when you twist the inner tie rod. If you are replacing the inner tie rod, the new one should have new lock nut with it.

Comment: Good to hear from you again.  You raise a good point:  if I could avoid using the inner tie rod tool and remove the inner TR with a crescent wrench then the problem is solved.

Comment: Grab a 4.5" angle grinder and some cutting discs, it might take a few minutes. You could use a sawz-all but it'll take longer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot of strong metal to cut through. I'd use a torch to cut through. Penetrating oil, heat and lots of leverage are easier than cutting this.

Comment: I was arriving at the same conclusion that if I can somehow wrench it off with oil, heat and elbow-grease, it would preferable / easier

Comment: Get proper penetrating oil and, a butane torch and 2 long pipe wrenches. Jam one against the ground and put all your weight on the other one.